# QML DropArea accept external drag

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I've noticed a new DropArea component in Qt5. I'm trying to drag a file from Finder (Mac) but only onEntered method is called.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: background;
    color: "white";
    width: 300;
    height: 300;

    DropArea {
        id: dropArea;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onEntered: {
            background.color = "gray";
            drag.accept (Qt.CopyAction);
            console.log("onEntered");
        }
        onDropped: {
            console.log ("onDropped");
        }
        onExited: {
            bckground.color = "white";
            console.log ("onExited");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is window creation code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickView qmlView;
    qmlView.setGeometry(0, 200, 600, 400);
    qmlView.setResizeMode (QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    qmlView.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/ivann/Projects/QtGuiTestApp/testView.qml"));
    qmlView.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe it helps you [link](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-qml/2011-December/003335.html)

Comment: @aleks_misyuk Thank you. Unfortunately, it's about local drag-n-drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a Mac-specific issue (it wokrs as expected on Linux at least). Filled a bugreport to Nokia: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27125

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the link attached by chebum that feature is not supported by QtQuick on any platform at the time of this writing.

Only posting for letting it know to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

QtQuick 5.2 supports drag and drop from external applications. See the example http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-externaldraganddrop-example.html